# How to get the column value of table for Excel sheet column values?

Tags: talend

In my Excel Sheet i have the product name ,i need to get primary key of the product from product master table and the same should be insert into transaction table , how i can perform this process by using talend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [tmap](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tMap) component. The tmap allows you to have the main data flow and perform lookups on that data and retrieve data from the lookups.